# executeUpdate() not working

Tags: jsp

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"); 

Connectioncon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST","db2admin","db2admin"); 

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

String v=request.getParameter("val");

String query="insert into value values('"+v+"')";

stmt.executeUpdate(query);               

stmt.close();

con.close();
```

I get an error saying that the server has encountered an error while servicing the executeUpdate() command. Cant seem to figure out the problem. I am using IBM DB2. Please help...

***Here, this is the error i keep getting***

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /check.jsp at line 26

23:         String read = "insert into `value` values(?)";
24:         PreparedStatement p = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(read);
25:         p.setString(1, request.getParameter("val"));
26:         p.executeUpdate();             
27:         p.close();
28:         con.close();
29:         out.println("Everything done..."); 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=`;insert into , DRIVER=3.62.56
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.check_jsp._jspService(check_jsp.java:99)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=`;insert into , DRIVER=3.62.56
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:676)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:127)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.c(jn.java:2614)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.d(jn.java:2602)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.a(jn.java:2094)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.a(kn.java:6720)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:141)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:41)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.gb(jn.java:2064)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.pc(kn.java:3214)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:3999)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.dc(kn.java:746)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeUpdate(kn.java:729)
    org.apache.jsp.check_jsp._jspService(check_jsp.java:85)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: In your table value, what is the data type of the column you are trying to insert? Is that a character data type or something else?

Comment: Are you using `createStatement` or `preparedStatement`? In your code posted above you are using `createStatement` and in exception it is shown as `preparedStatement`.

Comment: The data type of the column is BIGINT. Firstly i had tried with createStatement, then switched to preparedStatement. both the times i am getting the same error that executeUpdate() is not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hardcoding the value and seeing if it works? Have you tried to execute your sql statement directly on the database to make sure that you have the correct syntax?
See the safe insertion example below.

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DBurl, user, password);
        String read = "insert into `value` values(?)";
        PreparedStatement p = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(read);
        p.setString(1, request.getParameter("val"));
        p.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes, i tried hardcoding the value as well as executed the sql statement directly on the database.

Comment: also, change `setStr` to `setString`

Answer (score 0):

If your data type you are trying to insert is BIGINT, then `p.setString` will not work, because setString is used for setting character data type.

You have to use

```
p.setLong(1, request.getParameter("val"));
```

See the documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_rjvjdata.html)